# Javascript delete object form dictionary

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, arrays, object

I have a dictionary in java script, adding key and text on drag event.

Now when user click on this have to remove the key but it is not deleting from dictionary

```
 var buttonId = {};

 function drag(ev) {

                //buttonId.push(ev.target.id,ev.target.innerText);
                var index = Object.keys(buttonId).length;
                buttonId['[' + index + '].Key'] = ev.target.id;
                buttonId['[' + index + '].Value'] = ev.target.innerText;
            }
```

**Delete Function**

```
function Delete(key){
    delete buttonId[key];
    }
```

**spliceMethod** also din't work , I am using Jquery 2.0 , getting runtime error Object doesn't support property or method 'splice'

```
        var length = Object.keys(buttonId).length;
        for (var index = 0; index < length; index++) {
            var key = buttonId['[' + index + '].Key'];
            if (key == id) {
                buttonId.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Are you trying to do sth like buttonId1.key=sth,, butoonId2.key....sth like this?

Comment: wat is the `delete` returning(t/f)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it worked like this

```
  var length = Object.keys(buttonId).length;
                for (var index = 0; index < length; index++) {
                    var key = buttonId['[' + index + '].Key'];
                    if (key == id) {
                        delete buttonId['[' + index + '].Key'];
                        delete buttonId['[' + index + '].Value'];
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be using Javascript maps the way they are intended to be used. The proper pattern is:

```
buttonId[key] = value;
```

If you need to store complex data as the value, then do something like:

```
buttonId[key] = {id:ev.target.id, text:ev.target.innerText};
```

Comment: buttonId[key] = value , how do I get  key value form buttonId in another function

Comment: A dictionary/map looks up a value by key. If you need to search by buttonId, then make that your key. If you need to search by two different keys, then make two dictionaries.